# What is this musical notation: 0 vertically centered on staff after a barline?

Tags: notation, vibraphone

A friend of mine recently sent me this image of a piece of sheet music she had been given.
[image: Music]

This is music for vibraphone, and she is confused by the notation that appears to be a stretched whole note. So that it looks like a 0 (zero) vertically centered on the staff, just after a bar line.

I have been playing mallets for years now, and I have never encountered this notation before. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: What meter is this part of the piece in? Does the "0" change the meter or not?

Comment: Some more context on the part would help decipher the ntoation

Answer (score 2):

It could be a note cluster - play A B C or A Bb B C as a whole-note chord (assuming this is in the treble clef). I'm not a percussionist so I don't know how many notes you would normally include in a cluster - but using 4 mallets at once doesn't seem an excessive number!

Ref: https://w3c.github.io/smufl/gitbook/tables/note-clusters.html U+E129.

Comment: What meter is this part of the piece in? Does the "0" change the meter or not? If the "0" doesn't change the meter and the piece is in 4/4 here, then I question this answer.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Obviously you can make *guesses* which mean the answer might be invalid, but the OP didn't provide any information about the time signature - and FWIW much of the contemporary music I play has no time signatures at all. (That's not a modern invention - a lot lf 16th century music had neither time signatures, nor any "regular" rhythm that could be indicated by barlines).